# Where is my $PATH set?

Tags: unix, path, .profile

I'm trying to add a directory to my `$PATH` in mac OSX.

echo `$PATH` produces:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

logged in as user and doing: `vim ~/.profile` shows a different set of paths and adding to it doesn't change the path echo'ed from: `echo $PATH` (in a new shell)

I have looked in `~/.bash_profile` and its not there.
I've tried looking around when logged in as sudo su - but I can't find where the above path is set for me to edit it.

`echo $env` shows a blank line.

Comment: Mac OS X sets it in a TON of places 

take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard

Comment: adding into .bash_profile worked as suggested in an answer by another user which I would have accepted but it has apparently been deleted.

Comment: `echo $env`?? Do you have a *variable* named `env`?  Perhaps you wanted to say `env`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path to .bashrc and also to source it from your .bash_profile like so

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then 
    source ~/.bashrc 
fi
```

That way, when you set a PATH, it will apply to both.

Now when you login to your machine from a console .bashrc will be called.